# Insert html via .before() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right i'm trying to insert some basic html before a div like this

```
<script>$("div#header").before("<div class="test">test</div>");</script>
```

However nothing appears, but when i try the jquery example

```
<script>$("p").before("<b>Hello</b>");</script>
```

it works, what i'm i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The syntax highlighting in your question should give you a clue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [escape](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm) the quotation marks in the string literal like this:

```
"<div class=\"test\">test</div>"
```

Also, all DOM manipulation needs to occur *after* the browser has finished parsing the HTML document (also called "preparing the DOM"). The browser fires the "load" event for `document` when the "DOM is ready".

In jQuery, you write a callback for "DOM ready" like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#header").before("<div class=\"test\">test</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using exactly that code, you should be getting a JavaScript error due to the unterminated string.  Try this:

```
$('#header').before('<div class="test">test</div>');
```